# Images are not being rendered

Tags: android, titanium-alloy

I'm using newest version of titanium / alloy, under Windows 7 64 bit, Genymotion Android emulator (Samsung Galaxy S2, API 4.1.1), Titanium Studio build: 3.3.0.201407100905. Sample code:

```
<Window id="index" class="main-container">
    <View class="top">
        <View class="left top-left">
            <ImageView id="logo" image="/images/logo.png" />
            <ImageView id="title" image="/images/index_title.png" />
        </View>
        <View class="right top-right">
            <ImageView id="loginButton" image="/images/login_gray.png" />
        </View>
    </View>
</Window>
```

Always the first image is not being drawn (I get >[WARN] : TiDrawableReference: (pool-3-thread-2) [978,978] Could not open stream to get bitmap - in the console), but it doesn't depend on the picture - I mean if I do something like this:

```
<Window id="index" class="main-container">
    <View class="top">
        <View class="left top-left">
            <ImageView image="/images/non-existent-image.png" />
            <ImageView id="logo" image="/images/logo.png" />
            <ImageView id="title" image="/images/index_title.png" />
        </View>
        <View class="right top-right">
            <ImageView id="loginButton" image="/images/login_gray.png" />
        </View>
    </View>
</Window>
```

I will get the same error, but this time every other image will be drawn without any error. This hapens under every emulator, and device so I think it has something to do with Alloy / Titanium.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Deleting build folder solved the case.